# In ERD Can we have a relationship between 2 tables which are inheriting from one parent table?

Tags: sql, erd, table-relationships

If 2 tables, for example "Solo singer" and "Group singers" are inheriting from same parent table "Artists" , can we have a relationship between "Solo singer" and "Group singers"?

for example: 
A solo performer may be a member of many groups or of no group.
group is made up of one or more solo performers.

p.s I am aware that Many to Many relationships are discouraged but before going to that i want to know if that relationship is possible?

Comment: Could you show your ERD here?

Comment: Still I cannot add images.any other way to show?

Comment: Is there a group entity? If group singers are made of solo singer you should have table solo singer, table group and a relationship table between them.